# How do I output a Nested JSON that has no object name?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, nested

I have two JSONS... The first one is easily spent, the second one is nested in [[]]. How can I output the content?

Here is my code:

```
// First JSON
{
    "allSuSa": [
        {
            "accountlinevaluesId": 1,
            "accountlineId": 1,
            "mandantKagId": 660,
            "mandantAccountsId": 1,
            "period": "7",
            "accountNumber": 27,
            "name": "EDV-Hardware/Software",
            "amount": 55.16859
        }
   ]
}
```

```js
// My Solution
this.balanceListService.getDataForMonthlyAmount(`${this.year}`, monthStr).subscribe(
      (resp: any) => {
        let data = resp.allSuSa; // This works
```

```
// Second JSON 
{
    "monthlySusa": [ // first nesting
        [ // second nesting
            {
                "accountlinevaluesId": 1,
                "accountlineId": 1,
                "mandantKagId": 660,
                "mandantAccountsId": 1,
                "period": "7",
                "accountNumber": 27,
                "name": "EDV-Hardware/Software",
                "amount": 55.16859
            }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Just one additional `[0]`: for example, `resp.monthlySusa[0][0].accountlinevaluesId`

Comment: You seem to be asking how *arrays* work. This is very basic JavaScript. You need to run through some fundamental tutorials on JS and make sure you're comfortable before moving on to TS, RxJS and Angular.

Answer (score 1):

You can access this nested JSON like this.
Here `nestedJSON` is your nested object. So using `.` operator you can access the first hierarchy. Then you have `array` of `array`. And then first element of the inner `array`

```js
var nestedJSON = {
    "monthlySusa": [ // first nesting
        [ // second nesting
            {
                "accountlinevaluesId": 1,
                "accountlineId": 1,
                "mandantKagId": 660,
                "mandantAccountsId": 1,
                "period": "7",
                "accountNumber": 27,
                "name": "EDV-Hardware/Software",
                "amount": 55.16859
            }
    ]
  ]
}

console.log(nestedJSON.monthlySusa[0][0].accountNumber);
```